# authlogic without cookies, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, authlogic

I am developing server application with Ruby on Rails and I'd like to store session token in each request's body. For example `{"token":"asdkjahsdoahgfblkasblbag"}`.

And I am stuck, really don't know how to configure Authlogic to handle token from params, not via cookie. And how to prevent `set-cookie` header sending?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the module Authlogic::Session. This module is responsible for authenticating the user via params.

Please check: 
http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/params.rb

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Syed!

Unfortunately, I can't get it working.
Following is correct method to set params_key? No additional options needed?

class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  params_key :token
end